# Using $lookup to only return documents from a certain period of time

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to do a $lookup that joins two collections (users and runs, a one to many relationship)that have a discord_id field. However at the same time I am attempt to filter out all documents from the runs collection that do not fall within a certain period of time.
I have attempted to use the hexadecimal ObjectId strings in order to do this with a $match: $gte as shown below, but have not gotten it to return an array with any objects in it.

```
pipeline[
{ $match: { $gte: { _id: ObjectId("5f9506500000000000000000") } } }
]
```

End result should have a User object with many run objects in an array. The run objects should only be from within a specific time range.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

You can use `$toDate` to get the `time` factor from `ObjectId`. I have introduced some fields like `createDate` and `bool`. you can hide them using `$project` stage at the end.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "createDate": {
        $toDate: "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      bool: {
        "$gt": [
          "$createDate",
          {
            $toDate: ObjectId("5ab9c3da31c2ab715d421285")
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      bool: true
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qR0Wuc5T_94)